# C++ automatically update to new version

Tags: c++, version-control, download, version

I've been searching for a good solution for 3 days now, but I haven't been able to find any so far. My situation is:

A client has application installed (C++, console Application). The application on start-up will check it's version number with the server and get back or it is up-to-date or that it should download a new version.

If it has to download the new version, I would like to download the new script with Curl to the name say: **Application2.exe**

However, I want it to replace the old **Application.exe** which triggered the download of the new version.

My solution was: **Application.exe** downloads **Application2.exe**. When downloaded, it should trigger **Updater.exe** which sleeps for let's say 5 seconds. Within these 5 seconds (or whatever timespan which suites best). Within these 5 seconds, **Application.exe** has time to shutdown and after 5 seconds the **Updater.exe** replaces **Application.exe** with **Application2.exe**.

Now the update is finished and the client has the newest version installed.

Is this solution possible regarding system locking files, etc?

Comment: I'd do it the other way around.   Have a small program that checks for updates, applies any updates, and THEN runs the (updated) application.   The only problem comes if you need to update that "small program", but that shouldn't be needed nearly as often (its purpose is specialised and simple, so more chance of getting it right first time without bugs that drive a need for update).

Comment: You can also spawn another process to do the work and close your current program, allowing you to do whatever you like to the program because it's not running anymore!

Comment: @Peter, thanks for the heads-up, it's a nice solution indeed and I will think about it

Comment: @OMGtechy, thats the approach I stated above right? ..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Good news, you can rename files that are open on Windows (executables and DLLs). The lock prevents you from deleting files, not renaming them.

1. Rename the currently running program to `Application_old.exe` *while it's running*
2. Write the downloaded program to `Application.exe`
3. Run the new `Application.exe`
4. Close the old one.
5. Delete the old version using the new executed program.

This way, you'll have auto-restart after update. I do this myself all the time.

Comment: Wow, I didn't knew this... How can it be that when I do this on Windows with other programs it gives me the error message that the program is in use? Is it because your solution is made from within that same program?

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren This happens only with documents, for example, Microsoft Word documents. You can't rename them while they're open. But executables and DLLs are OK to be renamed.

Comment: Ah right, didn't mention you specifically stated for .exe and .dll files. Thanks I will think this through!